# How to verify whether the SQL server instance is correct or not using powershell?

Tags: sql-server, powershell, powershell-2.0

We are using Invoke-sqlcmd cmdlet to execute SQL query using powershell.

If SQl server instance is given as wrong it is throwing exception.

Though i have captured the error in try catch still it throw exception in console as

> "Invoke-Sqlcmd : A network-related or instance-specific error occurred
>   while establishing a connection to SQL Server"

```
            try {
            $Qresult= Invoke-sqlcmd -query $SelectQuery -ServerInstance $srvInstance
            $Qresult = $Qresult| % { $_.$columnName+"`n" }
            LogWrite "$Qresult`n"
        }
        catch {
            Write-error "Error occured when executing sql $SelectQuery"
            LogWrite $Error[0]
        }
```

How to verify whether SQL server instance is available and it is running before executing any query?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
function SQL-Ping-Instance 
{
    param (
        [parameter(Mandatory = $true)][string] $ServerInstance,
        [parameter(Mandatory = $false)][int] $TimeOut = 1
    )

    $PingResult = $false

    try
    {
        $SqlCatalog = "master"
        $SqlConnection = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection
        $SqlConnection.ConnectionString = "Server = $ServerInstance; Database = $SqlCatalog; Integrated Security = True; Connection Timeout=$TimeOut"
        $SqlConnection.Open() 
        $PingResult = $SqlConnection.State -eq "Open"
    }

    catch
    {
    }

    finally
    {
        $SqlConnection.Close()
    }

    return $pingResult
}

if (SQL-Ping-Instance $srvInstance)
{
    $Qresult= Invoke-sqlcmd -query $SelectQuery -ServerInstance $srvInstance
    $Qresult = $Qresult| % { $_.$columnName+"`n" }
    LogWrite "$Qresult`n"
}
else
{
    LogWrite "Couldn't contact $srvInstance"
}
```

Comment: In this param "[parameter(Mandatory = $false)[int] $TimeOut = 1
" you missed to put "]" before [int]. Please update that alone.

Answer (score 1):

Non terminating errors cannot be captured with try/catch. In order to make the error a terminating error, set the ErrorAction value to 'Stop'. If it doesn't help, try to add the -AbortOnError switch

```
try
{
   Invoke-sqlcmd -query... -ErrorAction Stop
}
catch
{
   $_
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use a powershell try/catch block to trap any errors - $_ will contain the full error description

```
cls
try
{
invoke-sqlcmd stuff here
}
catch
{
$_
}
```

You could also ping the server but trying to execute a command will test the server, test the instance, and test the database the query is run on all at the same time and your try/catch block will pick up any problems at each stage.

Comment: I have updated my question further. I was already using try catch